# LibGDX: Lag after loading textures

Tags: java, android, textures, libgdx

One part of my code looks like this:

```
public void goToMainMenu() {
        Assets.LoadMenuTexutres();
        Assets.unloadGameTexutres();
        game.setScreen(new MainMenuScreen(game));   
}
```

It works but when I call the method I get around .5 sec delay (because of loading Textures is heavy in OpenGL) and then I get to the MainMenuScreen but all the animation get choppy for around .3 seconds. Why do I get this choppy lag after I load assets/Textures and how do I prevent it?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use built-in [AssetManager](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/AssetManager)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your delays are because of:

1. All the loading of textures
2. All the unloading of textures, and then having the garbage collector run on the now free Bitmap objects

To avoid this delay from spoiling the user experience, I suggest you move the loading and unloading into an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), and show a [ProgressDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html) saying "Loading..." or something.